# Why there is an error while implementing interface "onmapreadycallback" in the following code?

Tags: java, android

The error is in:

> "public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback"

It is underlined in red ,saying either i declare my class "abstract" or implement an abstract method.

the hint says i could implement the method.
what does this mean?

```
    package autogenie.map;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);
    mGoogleApiClient = builder.build();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);



    }
```

Comment: that you need to implement the method´s provided by the interface

Comment: You code is missing implementation of  'onMapReady()' method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MapsActivity` claims to `implements OnMapReadyCallback` but it doesn't.

Add below to your `MapsActivity`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Your code here
}
```